# How can i create an object

Tags: java

I created this exercise because my mind is ''stuck'' on objects.

**Exercise :** I have a super class and I have 3 subclasses. Lets say I have a Car (super class). I have 1 subclass (Honda), 1 subclass (Nissan), 1 subclass (Subaru). Also, Honda class has 2 doors, Nissan has 4 doors and Subaru 1 door and 1 window.

**Questions : How can I create a car? How can I create a car Honda, Nissan, Subaru with this features?**
**What I am thinking and what am I doing in exercises :**

**First:** I create ''fields'' example inside the subclass Honda, Nissan, Subaru  I mean `private int windows;`

**Second:** I create getter and setter methods. Example:

```
public int getwindows(){return windows; }
```

and for set

```
public void setwindows(int ws){windows=ws;}
```

**Third:** I create the empty and full constructor .example :empty

```
public Honda() {} // of course i will create the same things in the other subclass and and the superclass Car
```

and full constructor

```
public Honda(int numberofpositioncar,int doors,int windows){super(numberofpositioncar); super.setUsing("Normal");} // i put more features to seemed more like an constructor
```

**Four:** Here is my problem should I create an array? Or 3 arrays for each category? Anyway, I create 3 arrays with objects. One for Honda one for Nissan and one for Subaru. Should I put it on the main, on the superclass or on the subclass? I put it usually on superclass. This code is false, it is what I have *tried* so far :

```
int N=10; // i create an array 10 slots -starting from 0 until 9 .
Car = new Car[N];
for(int i =0; i < car.length; i++) { 

            Car normalCar = new Honda();// i should give a price here ? and i will use the constructor of the subclass Hox ?
            Honda.setwindows(5); // that will create 5 windows? 
            Honda.getwindows(2); // or that will create 2 windows?


            Car[nCount] = sportCar;

            nCount++; 
        }
```

Comment: I've got to be honest, I don't exactly understand your issue here. Could you reword it a little? Is it just confusion about using super and sub classes and their properties?

Comment: That's better "answered" by reading some good resource on OOP in general and Java specifically. - IMHO

Comment: Hint: stackoverflow is not "programming school". You see, such questions can't be answered in a good way. You are more looking for people **explaining** stuff to you; like your teacher or your peers. This is not meant to be rude - just to let you know that your assumptions on what you can expect here ... are basically wrong.

Comment: I want to create cars and the windows in each case(if is Honda,subaru,Nissan)..It doesnt need for you to create the 3 of them just create  cars for Honda and the windows.Thats all i want simple.I dont asking do a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I know correctly, I think you want to create classes like this:

```
abstract class Car{
    abstract int getDoorCount();
    abstract int getWindowCount();
    abstract int getPrice();
}

class Honda extends Car{

    @Override
    int getDoorCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    int getWindowCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    int getPrice() {
        return 1000;
    }
}

class Nissan extends Car{

    @Override
    int getDoorCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    int getWindowCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    int getPrice() {
        return 2000;
    }
}

class Subaru extends Car{

    @Override
    int getDoorCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    int getWindowCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    int getPrice() {
        return 3000;
    }
}
```

When you want to create an array of cars. you can write in main or other method, like this

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Car[] cars = new Car[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cars[i] = new Honda();
        cars[i+10] = new Nissan();
        cars[i+20] = new Subaru();
    }

}
```

hope this help you :)

Comment: i think thats what i needed.On the class Nissan  you initialize what ''prices'' you want?example the door is 4 that means that you created a Honda and  with 4 doors .Right?

Comment: Yes, all you need is override the value of your own card :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you correct, you're asking where to keep your list/array with cars, right?

To be clear, a Class should ONLY do things it's directly related to.

e.g. a Car might have a method `drive()`, but it is responsible for taking care WHERE it is beeing stored.

other case, if you have multiple cars you might want to make a class garage with method like `addCar(Car car)`

In your case, just for keeping them in an array, you'd want to put that list into your main (or controller or whereever), but surely not into the base class.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think you need inheritance, super classes and subclasses here. It seems like the information you are trying to portray is that every car has a model, a number of doors, and a number of windows, etc. These can all be fields.

```
public class Car
{
    String model;
    int doors;
    int windows;
    // Price, position, etc...

    public Car(String model, int doors, int windows)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.doors = doors;
        this.windows = windows;
    }
}
```

As for *where* to instantiate the class - that should probably go in the `main` method, which gets executed wen you run this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(); // This is much more convenient than a fixed-size array
    cars.add(new Car("Honda", 2, 5));
    cars.add(new Car("Subaru", 1, 1));
    etc...
}
```

That being said, while we *can* answer these questions, I really recommend you find a java tutorial, and follow it through from start to finish. It will give you experience with the basic concepts, so when you want to do projects like this, you will have a better idea of where to start.